# Unity URP 2D Renderer replaces UI textures with black render textures on linux

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, urp

I recently installed Pop_OS (22.04) on my laptop and re downloaded my Unity 2021 Project.
On Windows it works perfectly fine, but when I enter play mode on Linux, all textures are black. Sometimes only UI elements show, sometimes nothing at all. Music is playing in the background.

I noticed in the Inspector, that my textures are being swapped for a TempBuffer rendertexture, which is black.

The edit mode looks like this:
[image: Edit Mode]

And in PlayMode:
[image: PlayMode]

Note the Texture in the inspector. I am certain that none of my scripts change this texture.

I suspect this is because I use the 2D renderer with the CameraSortingLayerTexture feature.
[image: renderer settings]

But turning i off also doesn't fix the issue. I am not sure why this is happening.

My Laptop also is not the newest model with only a Intel i3-5005U and no external graphics card.

Does anyone know why this could be happening?